# How can I do port mapping for kafka and Kubernetes: How to set advertised listener correctly?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am currently trying to expose Kafka outside of the Kubernetes cluster. And currently, it is working very randomly. Whenever I update the Kafka cluster using yaml file, sometimes it can consume and produce correctly, but sometimes it doesn't. This happens whenever I do rolling-update. The current pattern is that every second time that I try to re-update. It does not work. So it connects correctly with 50% chance. I am assuming I still have some issue in port mapping.

Here is my load balancer (currently using ebs):

```
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 31492
    nodePort: 31492
    targetPort: 9093
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Here is my kafka:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  serviceName: "kafka-svc"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 100
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - kafka
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        podAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
             - weight: 1
               podAffinityTerm:
                 labelSelector:
                    matchExpressions:
                      - key: "app"
                        operator: In
                        values:
                        - zk
                 topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: gcr.io/google_samples/k8skafka:v1
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: 500m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9093
          name: server
        - containerPort: 31492
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh; sleep 3000"]
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "exec kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties --override broker.id=${HOSTNAME##*-} \
          --override listeners='INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:31492' \
          --override listener.security.protocol.map='INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT' \
          --override advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://$(MY_POD_IP):9093,EXTERNAL://$(K8S_ELB_PORT_31492_TCP_ADDR):31492 \
          --override inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL \
          --override zookeeper.connect=zk-0.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:2181,zk-1.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:2181,zk-2.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:2181 \
          --override log.dir=/var/lib/kafka \
          --override auto.create.topics.enable=true \
          --override auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true \
          --override background.threads=10 \
          --override compression.type=producer \
          --override delete.topic.enable=false \
          --override leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300 \
          --override leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10 \
          --override log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000 \
          --override log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.retention.bytes=-1 \
          --override log.retention.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.jitter.hours=0 \
          --override log.segment.bytes=1073741824 \
          --override log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000 \
          --override message.max.bytes=1000012 \
          --override min.insync.replicas=1 \
          --override num.io.threads=8 \
          --override num.network.threads=3 \
          --override num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1 \
          --override num.replica.fetchers=1 \
          --override offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096 \
          --override offsets.commit.required.acks=-1 \
          --override offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000 \
          --override offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880 \
          --override offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000 \
          --override offsets.retention.minutes=1440 \
          --override offsets.topic.compression.codec=0 \
          --override offsets.topic.num.partitions=50 \
          --override offsets.topic.replication.factor=3 \
          --override offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600 \
          --override queued.max.requests=500 \
          --override quota.consumer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override quota.producer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override replica.fetch.min.bytes=1 \
          --override replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500 \
          --override replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000 \
          --override replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000 \
          --override replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536 \
          --override replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override request.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override socket.request.max.bytes=104857600 \
          --override socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override unclean.leader.election.enable=true \
          --override zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override zookeeper.set.acl=false \
          --override broker.id.generation.enable=true \
          --override connections.max.idle.ms=600000 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.enable=true \
          --override controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000 \
          --override controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override default.replication.factor=1 \
          --override fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override group.max.session.timeout.ms=300000 \
          --override group.min.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override inter.broker.protocol.version=0.10.2-IV0 \
          --override log.cleaner.backoff.ms=15000 \
          --override log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728 \
          --override log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000 \
          --override log.cleaner.enable=true \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=524288 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=1.7976931348623157E308 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0 \
          --override log.cleaner.threads=1 \
          --override log.cleanup.policy=delete \
          --override log.index.interval.bytes=4096 \
          --override log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime \
          --override log.preallocate=false \
          --override log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 \
          --override max.connections.per.ip=2147483647 \
          --override num.partitions=1 \
          --override producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.backoff.ms=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576 \
          --override replica.fetch.response.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override reserved.broker.max.id=1000 "
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
          value : "-Xmx512M -Xms512M"
        - name: KAFKA_OPTS
          value: "-Dlogging.level=INFO"
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /var/lib/kafka
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
           command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --bootstrap-server=localhost:9093"
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      storageClassName: standard
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

For internal listener, I am assigning each pod's ip, but one concern is that it is using the secondary ip from the kafka aws instance. I am not sure whether that is okay. (Hopefully this makes sense)
Is there any part that I missed to set up port mapping? I am mostly concerned about advertised listener for kafka.

Answer (score 1):

The advertised listener must be unique per pod. If you are running multiple pods in your stateful set, you will need to have a external load balancer port or address dedicated to each broker, ie three replicas = three different load balancer ports. Then set the advertised listener for each pod to it's external port.

Comment: is there any other way that I can avoid using creating different load balancers?

Comment: Not really. Kafka clients must be able to connect to a particular broker depending which is the leader of the partition being written to (so, the one accepting any writes), or the broker containing a partitions data. Therefore you need an external address for each broker, you cant simply have one load balancer forwarding all traffic.